# What does "anti-beltway" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Does it mean "anti-America" like this [link](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/beltway)? If so, it's very strange because South Korea is a big ally of the U.S.

> Things keep changing, but according to an amalgamation of media reports voters are likely to pick one of the following presidential candidates -- all reform-minded liberals or **anti-beltway** people. They would need to register next month for an election in May.

<sub>source: [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/ralphjennings/2016/11/09/5-sad-and-creepy-things-you-should-know-about-south-koreas-presidential-scandal/#96eb88c1556b)</sub>

Comment: [read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside_the_Beltway)

Comment: The "beltway" is a metonym for all those "insiders" who walk the corridors of power (in Washington DC) --see CowperKettle's link. To be anti-beltway in the US is to be of the opinion that your interests are not being served by the federal government, that your needs are being ignored, and that only the rich and powerful have the ear of Congress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The Beltway" is Interstate 495, which encloses Washington, DC.[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstate_495_(Capital_Beltway))

"Inside The Beltway" generally refers the activities of the US Government as to policy and attitudes. But, usually, "inside The Beltway" does not refer to the government itself, only to current personalities and policy makers within the government.

"Anti-beltway" suggests opposition to the policies and attitudes of the people, or personalities, influencing the US government at any given time. But "anti-beltway" is not a well defined term,

The *Forbes* citation in the question does not make clear how "anti-beltway" was used. I would not think the use of "anti-beltway" was very good journalism. I think it would be best not to be very concerned about writings on politics, particularly by one who would use the term "anti-beltway", which has no fixed definition.

Comment: Politicians come and go, but the attitude that the people at large would be lost without firm guidance from within the Beltway remains.  I think that is what “anti-beltway people” resent most of all.